# Bounded set open on addition?

Tags: metric-spaces

In one of my math classes, I have a theorem that starts with the following : 
Let T be a non-empty set, and X a subset of  B(T) [that is the set of bounded real value functions] that is closed under addition by positive constant functions, that is f element of X implies f + a is also element of X for any a > 0.

I just don't get how it is possible that I can add any value to a bounded set and stay within the set?  There's obviously something I don't understand properly, because adding a big enough constant would cause the value to go off bounds.

Can someone explain me what this actually means?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Each element is a bounded function $\ne$ a bounded set of functions.

Comment: For analogy: $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, ...\}$ is a set of numbers, each and every one of which is bounded. But $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded.

Comment: Ahhh, I get it.  If you add a finite constant to any bounded function, the function remains bounded.  I thought the bounds were on the value the functions could take, but that definition makes more sense.  Thanks a lot, really appreciated.